# Styles on secondary menu wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, content-management-system, wordpress-theming

Im using the secondary menu option in wordpress like this...

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'secondary' ) ); ?>
```

My question is: how do I change the styles in this secondary menu? Because all I get is a UL menú... Where can I edit the styles from the secondary menú?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You style more or less "everything" in your themes style.css file (/wp-content/themes/your-theme/style.css) Firebug http://getfirebug.com/ is by the way excellent tool as you can inspect specific elements and it shows what css it has and what file provides that css.

Comment: There is by the way stackexchange site dedicated to wordpress. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to add your own css classes to your menu? See this page for reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

As you can see you can add multiple arguments, like containers & menu classes or id's. To style an element from your menu, you should add a class to that element. You can do that by going to Appearance -> Menu. First make sure that the Screen Options menu(see the top right corner of your page), has CSS classes activated. Then you can select a page and add it's own class.

You can use css to style your classes.